# To disable and remove the ping service

Tags: services

Does it just possible to use only firewalls or software restrictions on operating systems to do it?
Can the service itself be disabled without the need for other software? (Example systemctl disable systemd-resolved).
Even I delete the iputils package, able to respond to ping requests on the network. Why?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Ping is actually done with the [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets responding to echo commands.

You can run the following on the system to turn off the response to ping:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
```

To reenable it run the following:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=0
```

Comment: By executing the following two commands
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 0

It is still possible to send  ICMP packets to my  Network interface as well as to my system RAM for parsing?

Comment: @hamizahedi You only execute one or the other but not both together.  It only disables the echo part that controls the response to ping.  Everything else should still work.

Comment: OK.
I understood.
My purpose for this talk is that I  want to know what are the limitations of the packages that enter my system memory for processing by the operating system to be analyzed.

Comment: I suggest that you mean "packets",  in the TCP/IP concept space, not "packages" which are in the post office/courier space. All packets addressed to the IP address that the Network Interface Card has (or one of the broadcast addresses)  are transferred to RAM and analyzed by the system, according to the fields in the TCP/IP headers and the system's rules.